# Function to save a video(OpenCV python)

Tags: python, opencv

Does anyone know any function for saving a video in openCV.

Preferably a function to be able to work with it.

I've tried to implement but I couldn't

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Have you done any research?

Comment: i already resolve that. thanks, if you want to see that question hihi

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60907884/how-increment-filename-in-pythonopencv

Answer (score 0):

OpenCV has VideoWriter API that you can use.
See the below example code:

```
##define the video writer
out = cv2.VideoWriter(<filename_with_extention>,<compression_format>, <frames_per_second>, (frame_width,frame_height)) 

## write a frame in the loop
out.write(<your_frame>)

## Release the video writer outside of the scope of the loop 
out.release()
```

Comment: yes, but needed a function to implement with another code

Comment: Sorry, I might not be able to understand clearly here. What do you mean by "with another code".

Comment: I have a program that selects points in a video and tracks them. And I wanted a function that recorded this video, already with the tracking points

Comment: like that:   
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60903066/how-to-save-a-video-opencv-with-selected-points-and-track-on-them

it's the problem i want to resolve :x

Comment: Ok, while reading and parsing through the input video, you can write the frames which have your tracked points in the VideoWriter object separately. 

When the input video parsing is finished, you can release VideoWriter object.

Comment: Exactly, I tested it but I couldn't: x, did you see the code on the link I sent?

Comment: if you could help with the code: x I've been trying this for two days and nothing xd

Comment: I had it on the def save video but I deleted it

Comment: but is something like that:
```
def save_video(outPath, fps, mirror=False):    

    out = cv2.VideoWriter(outPath, fourcc, fps, (int(width), int(height)))    

    while(cap.isOpened()):    

        if(check==True):    

            out.write(frame)    
```

Comment: I couldn't see your frame writing part of the code. Before the line cv2.imshow("Frame", frame) you can write out.write(frame). 
Also, why are there 2 while True loops? You should have one while True: loop. I would suggest editing in that question with latest code.

Comment: first while is to stop the video and choose the points, when i press 'p' the video continue with the trackng

Comment: Before any loop starts, write 
out = cv2.VideoWriter(outPath, fourcc, fps, (int(width), int(height))) 
Inside the loop write, out.write
Lastly, release is at correct position. No need to call separate save_video function

Comment: write out.write inside that loop?

Comment: and the argument ??

Comment: Yes out.write(frame) should be inside the loop. Just before your cv2.imshow(frame). Adding the updated code in the other question.

Comment: hmm, outPath is not defined

Comment: yes, it should be the name of the file.. say "my_video.avi"

Comment: man! you save my life <3

Comment: Please upvote :) Also I would suggest avoiding 2 while loops somehow. Ideally, there should not be two while True loops.

Comment: theoretically the first while ends after pressing a key, starting the other, but yes I will see about it, thank you again! given upvote :)

Comment: My pleasure, and yes you are correct from the logical point of implementation flow.

Comment: yeah nice, thanks again!

Comment: sry for another question xd, are we able to save several videos, or is it replaced every time we play the saved video?